# How to add a new 2fa account without using a second device to generate the QR code

Tags: android, ios, security, totp

Normal 2fa authentication flow when enabling the service is to have a website where you enable the 2fa, get a QR code and scan it with your totp app (Authy or Google Authenticator).

However how should we proceed if we don't have a second screen to scan the QR code from - for example a mobile app that is standalone but still requires 2fa for some actions. Is there a way to automatically register a new 2fa account, without having to manually copy paste the 2fa secret into the totp app.

Comment: Try to make a screen copy where you see the QR code then in the app checking for code there is sometimes possibility to get it from photo gallery or camera roll.

Comment: The 2FA setup process usually has an option to show an alphanumeric code instead. This can be copied and pasted into the Authenticator app.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Two-factor authentication with Google Authenticator - manually type key instead of scanning QR code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47267583/two-factor-authentication-with-google-authenticator-manually-type-key-instead)